# Autogenerate id in Cosmos DB from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I generate an autoincremented Id in a Cosmos DB if I do a POST request from Spring Boot.

Comment: Cosmos DB does not have support for autoincrement. You will need to implement this yourself.

Comment: Is there any reference for it.

Comment: Why would there be docs on something that is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

The docs explain the behavior here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos#spring-data-annotations

```java
public class GeneratedIdEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
}
```

As mentioned, Cosmos uses UUIDs rather than an auto-increment long.

Comment: Is there any document reference?

Answer (score 0):

Use
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String id;